# Integrating Payement Gateway in Android

Tags: android

I have to integrate Payement gateway to my android app.

- Which is the best one for this?
- Is those gateways are free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have integrated two types of Payment Gateways in Mobile Applications.

1. Paypal
2. Authorize .net

Both of them are easy to use. Development work is same in both of them. But Paypal is good like many factors, because paypal have 2 kind of payment facility as a development level. It is MECL and MPL. Its efficient, speedy and with highly security.

So I recommend you Paypal.